# HTMLEditorExtender from ASP.NEt AJAX Control Toolkit clientside onchange

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use the new `HTMLEditorExtender`. I was wondering if there is any way to add client side `onkeyup`, `onchange`, etc. event on it? It does not seem to work if the events are placed on `textbox` which is being extended.

Answer (score 2):

if you take a look at the "textbox" element you will notice it is not an actual textbox, but a div that allows you to "write" text on it. When I inspected the element I saw it was a "div" and the "id" was "ctl00_SampleContent_txtBox1$HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior_ExtenderContentEditable" (it might be different in your html). So, try and find the "id" of your element and attach these events to it and I am sure it will work (see picture at the end, it worked for me). Also it'd be better if you add the "javascript" and "jquery" tags  to your question so that more people look at it. Good luck!

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIZnc.png)